# Why have I got a blank map using cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

i'm develop an hybrid app with cordova framework and jquery mobile. I use cordova-plugin-googlemaps instead of google maps javascript api v3 to improve the performance of my app. When I run my app on android device it displays a blank map. I use this tutorial [Tutorial for Windows to add cordova-plugin-googlemaps][1]

[1]: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows to add cordova plugin and this [Blank Map][2]

[2]: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/TroubleShooting:-Blank-Map to resolve my problem but i haven't solved. Help me, please!

p.s.: i'm sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old question, but some people still access from this page.
I update this answer.

JesseMonroy650's answer is mis-leading. Because the original questioner describes **"he/she  uses cordova-plugin-googlemaps instead of google maps javascript api v3"**.

[cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) is a wrapper plugin of "Google Maps SDK for Android" and "Google Maps SDK for iOS" at 2015.

"cordova-plugin-googlemaps" provides original JavaScript API of those native SDKs.
But in the behind, the plugin manipulate native APIs, and those native APIs do not follow the `white-list` rules at all, because it's not JavaScript.

---

Many people ask me **"Why I get blank map?"**

There are two reasons:

1) If you mean "blank map" is "gray map", then it's your API key authentication problem.
Most people are this case.

[image]

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/troubleshootings/graymap/README.md

2) If you mean "white map" (you can not see the map at all), probably you hide the map with `background-color` or some another DOM.

Because the maps plugin displays native Google Maps View **under browser view**.

[image]

3) Even if you can't solve your problem, please ask me at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues

Answer (score 0):

When you access any resources or assets not on the webpage you need to use a `whitelist`.

### The fix to many common *white-list* problems

The alternative is this quick fix – but know that this *quick fix* removes all needs for `white-list`. This creates a [security issue](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-webview-security-582363/) which you may not want to by pass.

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml` for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

The long answer is as such:

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1 and cli-5.2.0. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.
>
> Lastly, Raymond Camden in his blog points to a [LARGE change in policy starting with Cordova 5](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5)

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: I installed the latest version of both cordova and googlemaps plugin. I insert the meta-tag  "<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">" into .html file but the problem reamins. I see the blank map.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to let you look at my RAW NOTES for `white-list`. I'm working on a Blog post, but it will be a few days. I would recommend the DANGEROUS settings. https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-system.md